# OR criteria with DAVERAGE

Tags: excel, criteria

Given a large number of entries like the following:

```
type    quantity
apple   3
orange  6
pear    2
pear    2
orange  1
...
```

I know I can create a pull down menu where I can select any type, say 'apple' or 'orange' and get the average quantity for that specific type: to do so, I use daverage where the criteria is a cell with data validation (i.e. whose content is controlled by a pull down menu).

But what I would also like to have in my pull down menu is an entry 'apple or orange' which when selected gives me the average quantity for apple and orange combined.

I know I can use daverage to compute that number but I don't know how to use that in combination with a pull down menu to achieve my final goal so that by simply modifying the content of cell controlled by a pull down menu, I can obtain the average for either orange, or apple, or orange and apple combined.  Is there a way?

Comment: No: I was hoping for solution where the user would only have to select one criteria from a dropdown menu to get a specific average.  I resolved my issue with a workaround: I created a secondary type in a new column that is derived from the types and includes the combination I need (e.g. if type=orange or type=apple, the secondary type is orange-apple) and I used one of the values in that column as my criteria.  Not ideal but it does what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following pnuts' suggestion and the very same example data: I added a column isAppleOrOrange, computing yes or no using a following formula like this:

```
=IF(OR(A6="apple",A6="orange"),"yes","no")
```

This way, if you specify 'yes' in B2, you get the average for apple + orange combined.  You can still specify any fruit you want in B1 to get the average for a specific fruit alone but need to make sure isAppleOrOrange is left blank in that case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer regardless because though not suitable for you it may be suitable for others in a similar (but not identical!) situation:

Including blanks in data validation can have drawbacks but if applied only to the selection criteria (highlighted yellow) this can be advantageous (two blanks in A2:A3 and the overall average is shown). Treating `apple` and `orange` separately rather than as `orange-apple` is simpler (does not require your workaround) and flexible – any pair (rather than pear!) could be chosen without extending the validation list.

[image: SO20256629 example]